# How can I start ktor-server programmatically for Integration-Tests

Tags: ktor

KTor works nice with unit tests but how can I start my ktor server for integration tests?

This is how my test looks like:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class HttpClientTest {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpClientTest::class.java.name)

    companion object {

        @BeforeClass
        @JvmStatic
        fun setup() {
            // ?????
        }

        @AfterClass
        @JvmStatic
        fun teardown() {
            // ????
        }
    }


    @Test
    fun testMitDefaultHttpClient() {
        val httpget = HttpGet("http://0.0.0.0:8080/json/gson")
        httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")

        val httpclient: HttpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()
        val response = httpclient.execute(httpget)

        Assert.assertEquals(200, response.statusLine.statusCode.toLong())

        val responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.entity)
        logger.info(responseString)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

OK - found the solution:

```kotlin
package at.mikemitterer.catshostel.routes

import at.mikemitterer.catshostel.WsClientApp.main
import at.mikemitterer.catshostel.main
import io.ktor.application.Application
import io.ktor.application.call
import io.ktor.http.ContentType
import io.ktor.response.respondText
import io.ktor.routing.get
import io.ktor.routing.routing
import io.ktor.server.engine.applicationEngineEnvironment
import io.ktor.server.engine.connector
import io.ktor.server.engine.embeddedServer
import io.ktor.server.netty.Netty
import io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runBlockingTest
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils
import org.junit.*
import org.koin.test.KoinTest
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory


@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class HttpClientTest : KoinTest {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpClientTest::class.java.name)


    companion object {
        lateinit var server: NettyApplicationEngine

        @BeforeClass
        @JvmStatic
        fun setup() {
            val env = applicationEngineEnvironment {
                module {
                    main(true)
                }
                // Public API
                connector {
                    host = "0.0.0.0"
                    port = 8080
                }
            }
            server = embeddedServer(Netty, env).start(false)
        }

        @AfterClass
        @JvmStatic
        fun teardown() {
            // clean up after this class, leave nothing dirty behind
            server.stop(1000, 10000)
        }
    }


    @Test
    fun testMitDefaultHttpClient() {
        val httpget = HttpGet("http://0.0.0.0:8080/json/gson")
        httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")

        val httpclient: HttpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()
        val response = httpclient.execute(httpget)

        Assert.assertEquals(200, response.statusLine.statusCode.toLong())

        val responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.entity)
        logger.info(responseString)
    }
}
```